# Is it possible in Svelte to have #each loops with two-way binding to nested object values?

Tags: javascript, object, each, svelte

The following Svelte code works fine:

```
<input bind:value='options.name.value' placeholder='{{options.name.placeholder}}'>
<p>Hello {{options.name.value || 'stranger'}}!</p>
```

Using this JSON:

```
{
    "options": {
        "name": {
            "value": "",
            "placeholder": "enter your name"
        }
    }
}
```

[You can see it in action](https://svelte.technology/repl/?version=1.11.2&gist=97418a21fe86ff429e91807fcf3cdfa5).  But what if we want to loop over `options` with an `#each` array...is that possible?

It *almost* works if we do everything except the bind:

```
{{#each Object.keys(options) as option}}
<input bind:value='options.name.value' placeholder='{{options[option].placeholder}}'>
<p>Hello {{options[option].value || 'stranger'}}!</p>
{{/each}}
```

[You can see](https://svelte.technology/repl/?version=1.11.2&gist=2e30780a835612b1060372c64964445f) that the placeholder is correct, and the two-way binding works correctly.  But the code is not correct yet, because `options.name` is hard-coded in for the bind, instead of using the loop value.  If we [try to fix that](https://svelte.technology/repl/?version=1.11.2&gist=11d210426a866e136e6a862ebabae15f), putting `bind:value='options[option].value'`, we get a syntax error, `Expected '`.

So, if it's possible to two-way bind within a loop using the loop value, what's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**The short answer** is that yes, it's absolutely possible to use two-way binding inside an `each` block, but the value of the block has to be a straightforward array, rather than the outcome of an expression like `Object.keys(options)`:

```js
{#each options as option}
  <input bind:value={option.value} placeholder={option.placeholder}>
{/each}
```

```js
{
  "options": [
    {
      "id": "name",
      "value": "",
      "placeholder": "enter your name"
    },
    {
      "id": "email",
      "value": "",
      "placeholder": "enter your email"
    }
  ]
}
```

**The longer answer**, in which I think aloud for a few moments: using an expression (that isn't just a reference like `foo` or non-computed member expression like `foo.bar`) for two-way binding is an interesting challenge. There are actually two separate issues: firstly, distinguishing between valid expressions like `options[option].value` and expressions that wouldn't make any sense in a two-way binding context. Secondly, the `each` block expression creates a sort of barrier — if someone were to do this...

```js
{#each Object.keys(options) as option}
  <input bind:value={option}>
{/each}
```

...they'd be binding to a value that is essentially read-only. But you can't tell that just from looking at the syntax. So the static analysis would need to be smart enough to understand that binding to `options[option].name` is valid but binding to `option` isn't. Something for us to think about.

Finally, **the secret option** is to [not use two-way binding in this context](https://svelte.technology/repl/?version=1.11.2&gist=7b4846cbf71b0744b85f65733fb90f77), since it's really just a convenient wrapper around event listeners:

```html
<script>
  let options = {
    name: {
      value: '',
      placeholder: 'enter your name'
    }
  };

  function updateValue(option, value) {
    options[option].value = value;
  }
</script>

{#each Object.keys(options) as option}
  <input
    on:input="{() => updateValue(option, e.target.value)}"
    placeholder={options[option].placeholder}
  >
{/each}
```

Comment: Not using two-way binding would seem to preclude, e.g., having a checkbox with a  `<span>` in the each loop whose `on:click` also toggles the input.  You also can't put the logic within the each loop, since you can't use `refs` in each loops.  I guess for this one then has to use the array and just get used to using `Array.find()` in the code rather than hash key lookups.  :)

Comment: It also seems that using `component.observe` on a nested property doesn't fire anything when the property gets set, so you can't add the other half of the two-way yourself.

Comment: You can do `{{#each things as thing, i}}` and pass `i` to event handlers, which can work around the lack of `ref` inside `each` blocks (on which [see here](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/368)). `component.observe` only works with top-level properties ([issue here](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/369))

Comment: Hi @RichHarris is this still working on newest version of svelte? Is there a different syntax?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
  let options = {
    name: {
      value: '',
      placeholder: 'enter your name'
    },
  };
    
    $: console.table(options)
</script>

{#each Object.entries(options) as [key, option]}
  <input
    bind:value={option.value}
    placeholder={option.placeholder}
  >
{/each}
```

https://svelte.dev/repl/a77dd18da023469da962d873e6fb391f?version=3.47.0