# Svelte: Pass and bind data to child component in each loop

Tags: javascript, binding, bind, each, svelte

I am heavily confused about passing props to a component within a loop in Svelte. The behavior I expected of the code snippet below is that a change in the store variable *files* triggers re-rendering of the content which works flawlessly for the divs classes and `{file}: {is_open}`. However, the child component Icon does not receive the updates of the *is_open* variable. This leads to a weird situation where `{file}: {is_open}` renders as `filename: true` in this component while the child component *Icon* would display `filename: false` instead.

```
{#each Object.entries($files) as [file, is_open], i}
<div class:open={is_open} class:closed={!is_open}>

    <div on:click={() => openFile(file)}>
        {file}: {is_open}
    </div>

    <div on:click={() => closeFile(file)}>
        <Icon bind:open={is_open} />
    </div>

</div>
{/each}
```

Searching for a solution for this issue I stumbled upon
[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42737693/is-it-possible-in-svelte-to-have-each-loops-with-two-way-binding-to-nested-obje) which indicates that this is indeed the expected behavior in this case. But how can I make this work then? In stark contrast to my overall experience with Svelte, I find this extremely counterintuitive.

EDIT:

Turns out I do not directly use *is_open* in the child component but store the value in another variable without `$:` notation, hence this variable is not recomputed. My bad, problem solved.

Comment: Could you reproduce this in a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.46.4)?

Comment: In this simplified version it seems to work fine https://svelte.dev/repl/e6dacb65dfd54c18aea9c3142099ca12?version=3.46.4

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is a [keyed each block](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-each), this will make sure that the divs (the block within the each statement) will be mapped correctly to the right file state.

you can also check the [official svelte tutorial about keyed each](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/keyed-each-blocks)
in your case

```svelte
{#each Object.entries($files) as [file, is_open], i (file)} <!--added (file)-->
<div class:open={is_open} class:closed={!is_open}>

    <div on:click={() => openFile(file)}>
        {file}: {is_open}
    </div>

    <div on:click={() => closeFile(file)}>
        <Icon bind:open={is_open} />
    </div>

</div>
{/each}
```